# Using custom fonts with an SVG inside a .NET Core application

Tags: svg, .net-core, fonts

I'm struggling to get an SVG file to use the correct fonts and am working with the following code:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1318.72 202.13">
  <defs>
    <style>
        .cls-1 {
        fill: #2cb04b;
        font-family: HalisGR-ExtraLight;
        src: url('../fonts/HalisGR-ExtraLight.otf');
        }

        .cls-1, .cls-2 {
        font-size: 144px;
        }

        .cls-2 {
        fill: #0071a6;
        font-family: Adrianna-Bold;
        src: url('../fonts/Adrianna-Bold.otf');
        font-weight: 700;
        }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(0 122.4)"><tspan x="0" y="0">MY</tspan></text>
  <text class="cls-2" transform="translate(448.12 125.04)"><tspan x="0" y="0">TITLE</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

I've tried several variations of this with no success so far. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Embedding fonts using a URL is [not supported](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG/issues/967#issuecomment-1094333797) by svg-net. As far as I know, svg-net relies entirely on OS-based font resolving.

Every font that needs to be used for rendering must be [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76340353/fonts-not-loading-in-png-jpg-while-converting-svgdocument-to-bitmap/) on your operating system.